# Fix query to fetch all rows matching a query into associative array instead of just one

Tags: php, pdo, count

In by Database, there are 6 rows where city_name equals "San Antonio" (identical in spelling, capitalization, and spacing). I have the following code for my selection of location id's.

```
function search_locations(string $term): array
{

    global $db;

    $sql = 'SELECT location_id FROM cities
            WHERE
            city_name LIKE :term';
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindparam(':term', $term);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

When I run that command within my function and then check the array using

```
<?php $id_array = search_locations($search_term); ?>
<pre>
<?php print_r( $id_array); ?>
</pre>
```

I get the following

> ```
> Array (
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [location_id] => 38
>     )
>
> )
> ```

This only shows one location is being found. BUT if add into my query the following before my return statement

```
$cSql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cities WHERE city_name LIKE :term';
$cStmt = $db->prepare($cSql);
$cStmt->bindParam(':term', $term);
$cStmt->execute();

// To just see the result without violating return rules
exit($cStmt->fetchColumn());
```

I get 6 results. Keep in mind I have also changed the first query to say

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM cities
            WHERE
            city_name LIKE :term';
```

and still only got one element within the main array with all the field values for only the first row that appears in the table with that city_name equal to "San Antonio"

**EDIT**

After putting the concise code through the file I noticed that this result doesn't happen if I just call the code as placed above. But there is more code involved that I didn't think was related. Adding that below now.

```
<?php
require_once '../../private/initialize.php';
if (is_post_request() && $_POST['search_term'] !== "") {
    $search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
    $id_array = search_locations($search_term);
    // Its Fine here
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r( $id_array);
    echo '</pre>';

    $location = [];
    $cities = [];
    $zips = [];
    $phones = [];
    $urls = [];
    foreach ($id_array as $item) {
        array_push($location, find_location_by_id($item['location_id']));
        array_push($cities, find_cities_by_location_id($item['location_id']));
        array_push($zips, find_zips_by_location_id($item['location_id']));
        array_push($phones, find_phones_by_location_id($item['location_id']));
        array_push($urls, find_urls_by_location_id($item['location_id']));
    }
} else {
    redirect_to(url_for('lookup/test_search.php'));
}

$page_title = 'Results for "' . $search_term . '"';
include_once SHARED_PATH . '/search_header.php';

if (!empty($id_array)) { ?>
    <?php
    if (sizeof($id_array) === 1) {
        // Its bad here
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $id_array);
        echo '</pre>';
} ?>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the code here could work as you aren't passing the sql string to `prepare()`. Assuming that's just a typo in the question? I'd just like to be sure we're seeing the same code you're running.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo. I was free typing to make the question concise.

Comment: Concise is good! As long as it doesn't impede reproducibility :)

Comment: Actually, the `$db->prepare();` is where it is prepared. Its a PDO statement, and both versions of that DO show the `$db->prepare();`

Comment: It's very odd that `fetchColumn()` would somehow show six results, since it fetches a single value from one row.

Comment: MY THOUGHTS EXACTLY!!! But here is the other thing . . . I just put in this concise code without some other code that doesn't even call on that array . . . and somehow its returning correctly on the fetch. So something else on my calling php file is altering the array after this query is called. It has nothing to do with my query.

Comment: Well, if you want to add some of that code, maybe someone could suggest what might be happening there. There aren't any answers yet, so it shouldn't really matter even if you end up changing the question substantially.

Comment: I was doing that as you suggested it.

Comment: I agree there's nothing there that obviously modifies `$id_array`. I'd suggest checking that search_header.php doesn't do anything to it, and make sure there are not global references to it in any of those other find_ functions.

Comment: Would going through the array modify it?

Comment: Just iterating it with foreach? No. That in itself doesn't affect the array. Something inside the loop could be, but not the loop itself.